# Spring, Kafka and Mongo how to create a RestController

Tags: java, rest, spring, mongodb, apache-kafka

I'm learning how to use Kafka, I've never used something similar in the past. In my job I was required to create a POC using it and integrate it to Spring Boot and save information on MongoDB (because we will need to retrieve information on-demand and I thought that it would be the best approach).

At the consumer I created an app, but I'm not sure if I should have a `@RestController` class or this is something that should go into Kafka and how?

Is it ok to have the `MyRestController` class? If not, how do I implement this using Kafka?

Right now, the code is working but I would like to improve it especially the Controller part and any extra comments that you could make to improve this.

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

**KafkaConfigurator**

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import com.example.demo.model.User;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory; 
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, User> userConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> userKafkaListenerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(userConsumerFactory());
        return factory; 
    }
}
```

**MyRestController**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.listener.KafkaConsumer;
import com.example.demo.model.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "users")
public class MyRestController {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer consumer;

    @GetMapping(path = "/findUserByOffset/{offset}")
    public User getUserByOffset(@PathVariable("offset") Long offset) {
        return consumer.getUserByOffset(offset);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/findUsersInRange/{lowerOffset}/{upperOffset}")
    public List<User> getUsersByOffsetRange(@PathVariable("lowerOffset") Long lowerOffset, @PathVariable("upperOffset") Long upperOffset) {
        return consumer.getUsersByOffsetRange(lowerOffset, upperOffset);
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.factory;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import com.example.demo.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long>{
    User findById(String id);
    User findByOffset(Long offset);

    @Query("{'offset' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 }}")
    List<User> findInOffsetRange(Long lowerOffset, Long upperOffset);
}
```

**KafkaConsumer**

```
package com.example.demo.listener;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.factory.UserRepository;
import com.example.demo.model.User;

@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Kafka_Example", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println("Consumed message: " + message);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Kafka_Example_json", groupId = "group_json", containerFactory = "userKafkaListenerFactory")
    public void consumeJson(User user) {
        System.out.println("Consumed JSON message: " + user);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User getUserByOffset(Long offset) {
        return userRepository.findByOffset(offset);
    }

    public List<User> getUsersByOffsetRange(Long lowerOffset, Long upperOffset) {
        return userRepository.findInOffsetRange(lowerOffset, upperOffset);
    }
}
```

**User**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    private Long salary;
    private Long offset;

    public User(String id, String name, String dept, Long salary, Long offset) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.dept = dept;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public Long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Long getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    public void setOffset(Long offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + ", dept=" + dept + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }
}
```

**KafkaConsumerDemoApplication**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaConsumerDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaConsumerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
#server
server.port=8081

#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=app1

#logging
logging.level.org.springframework.data=debug
logging.level.=error
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-consumer-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-consumer-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question and code, I understand that you are trying to

- consume events from Kafka topic, persist in MongoDB.
- Also, exposing api's to retrieve data from Mongo DB and send in response.

If this is the case, solution above looks Good, as you are considering MongoDB as a source of truth/primary DB.

you can also persist data in Kafka as a cache and use configure API's to get data from Kafka. (Refer KTable, GlobalKTable).